# Call a function once only after data has been received from @input (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Ive got a component that gets some data passed in from a parent component via an input so..

**main.component.ts**

```
<app-sidebar [data]="programData"></app-sidebar>
```

then in my

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
@Input() data: Entry<any>;
```

now this data has a unique id in its response and that id is used as a parameter in another function that calls some data that then populates an element on my page, so Ive been able to get it to work by putting the function in the `ngOnChanges` but obviously everytime something changes it recalls that function.. is there a way to call a function but only after I have recieved the data from the `Input() data`?

my current set up is as follows:

```
 ngOnChanges() {
    this.id = this.data.fields.id; // sets the id from the @input() data
    this.getElements(this.id); //gets the other data using the passed in id
 }
```

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, I only want to set the `this.id` the first time, not everytime the data changes, the data that is coming in is from an api so you have to allow for the data to come in the first time

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
If you only want to set the `id` if the data is set for the first time, you do that in the `OnChanges` lifecycle hook and check if the id is already set:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(changes.data && changes.data.currentValue) {
    const fields= changes.data.currentValue.fields;
    if(fields && (fields.id || fields.id === 0) && (!this.id && this.id !== 0)) {
      this.id = data.fields.id;
      this.getElements(this.id);
    }  
  }
}
```

And just in case if you want to set the id only if the id changed, use:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(changes.data && changes.data.currentValue) {
    const fields= changes.data.currentValue.fields;
    if(fields && (fields.id || fields.id === 0) && fields.id !== this.id) {
      this.id = fields.id;
      this.getElements(this.id);
    }  
  }
}
```

---

The [**OnChanges**](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges#ngOnChanges) lifecycle hook has a parameter of type [**SimpleChanges**](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges). You should use it to only react to a change of the `data`-input.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(changes.data && changes.data.currentValue) {
    const data = changes.data.currentValue;
    this.id = data.fields.id;
    this.getElements(this.id);
  }
}
```

Or as an alternative, you could use a `setter` for your input:

```
private _data: Entry<any>;

@Input()
set data(value: Entry<any>) {
  this._data = value;
  this.id = value.fields.id;
  this.getElements(this.id);
}

get data() {
  return this._data;
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is that the data in data does change, I just want to set the id the first time and then when the data changes not have the id change

Comment: You didn't stated that in your question, i'll update my answer.

Comment: Your updated answer doesnt work because the data from the input hasnt been recieved until after the view has been init

Comment: You also didn't mentioned that the data won't be available as soon as the component is initialized. But okay i'll update it again

Comment: Sorry I thought that would of been self explanatory.. I will update the question

Comment: Edited and also checked if the id is zero to pass it, because `!this.id` would be `true` if the id is `0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a setter for this (the code inside is called everytime the value of passed input has changed):

```
@Input('data')
set data(value: Entry) {
    // do something with incoming data
}
```

Comment: The problem Im having is that the data does change, I just want to set the id the first time the data comes in and not when the data changes